# Symfony2 stop Composer installing parameters.yml.dist into parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, parameters, composer-php

New in symfony 2.3 the `composer install` script also copies the `parameters.yml.dist` file contents into the `parameters.yml` file, explained further [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file).

My question is, how can I stop composer preforming this action?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Remove this line twice from your `composer.json`:

```
"Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
```

This is done by the IncenteevParameterHandler library, which contains a script that does this. By removing the script from the config, it will never be called.

If you remove that line for ever, you can also remove these lines (as the library isn't really needed anymore):

```
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

...

"incenteev-parameters": {
    "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
},
```

Comment: It's not though. All that's happening is that Composer now won't call the buildParameters method of the ScriptHandler. It's not even part of the core symfony code, it's a 3rd party bundle. (So it's removal won't have any side-effects.) It's included in the standard distro though, since it's really useful when working in teams - even if it's just 2 people -, so ultimately I wouldn't recommend removing this functionality.

Answer (score 58):

**First solution** : add *"keep-outdated": true* in the *'extra'* section of your *composer.json*.

```
[...]
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "keep-outdated": true  <------------ ADDED LINE ------------
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    },
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
}
[...]
```

*incenteev* will not remove parameters any more.

**Second solution** : modify the *app/config/parameter.yml.dist* file.
For me it was to add Sqlite parameters *'path'* and *'memory'* and avoid to see them deleted each time I do a *composer update*.

```
# app/config/parameter.yml.dist
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_sqlite
    database_host:     ~
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     ~
    database_user:     ~
    database_password: ~
    database_path:     ~ <------------ ADDED LINE ------------
    database_memory:   ~ <------------ ADDED LINE ------------
[...]
```

I don't know which solution is the best but both works.

Comment: I like the second solution the best as it forces you to manifest all your project's parameters in the ``parameter.yml.dist`` so that everyone who exports your project knows about them.

Answer (score 4):

leaving empty this array of parameters:

```
"incenteev-parameters": {
    "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
},
```

in the extra section of your composer.json file should work.

```
"incenteev-parameters": {},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct solution in my opinion:

```
"incenteev-parameters": {
    "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
    "keep-outdated": true
},
```

It was mentioned in this github issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/642 as well as in the github documentation for incenteev-parameters https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler