# Override FOSUser Registration Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to add two field "Name" and "FirstName" in the FosUser Registration Form, but it doesn't work.
Here is what I do :

CulturalStore/UserBundle/Ressources/config/services.yml :

```
services:
cultural_store_user.registration.form.type:
    class: CulturalStore\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    arguments: [%cultural_store_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: cultural_store_user_registration }
```

CulturalStore/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType :

```
<?php

namespace CulturalStore\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('firstname');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cultural_store_user_registration';
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return 'cultural_store_user_registration';
    }
}
```

CulturalStore/UserBundle/Entity/User.php, I add :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Entrez votre prénom.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max="255",
 *     minMessage="Prénom trop court.",
 *     maxMessage="Prénom trop long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $firstname;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Entrez votre nom.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max="255",
 *     minMessage="Nom trop court.",
 *     maxMessage="Nom trop long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $name;
```

In app/config.yml I have :

```
registration:
    confirmation:
        from_email:
            address:        "contact@culturalstore.com"
            sender_name:    "noreply - CulturalStore"
        enabled:    true
        template:   CulturalStoreUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    form:
        type: cultural_store_user_registration
```

But I have this error :

ParameterNotFoundException: The service "cultural_store_user.registration.form.type" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "cultural_store_user.model.user.class".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in services file: `arguments: [%cultural_store_user.model.user.class%]`

should be replaced with `arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]`

Also read [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md)

Comment: Thx, It seems better :)
I have now this error :/ : AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Assert\NotBlank" in property CulturalStore\UserBundle\Entity\User::$firstname was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: @user2178964 make sure you have `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in your `CulturalStore/UserBundle/Entity/User.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    cultural_store_user.model.user.class: CulturalStore\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding something in parameters.yml, offen we don't add anything in this file because it's almost only for database parameters no ?
I try your trick but I now have : AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Assert\NotBlank" in property CulturalStore\UserBundle\Entity\User::$firstname was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: You have to add it in the bundles parameters.yml, not in the global one because it's overwritten each time you run composer (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451695/symfony2-stop-composer-installing-parameters-yml-dist-into-parameters-yml if you want to prevent that).
The new error is because you don't added the Assert annotation in the use statement. Add `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` on top of the entity