# Why composer update delete me a parameter?

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, yaml, composer-php

I use a Sqlite data base so in my config.yml I used the path to my Sqlite file like this :

```
path: "%database_path%"
```

And in my parameters.yml I defined like this :

```
database_path : '%kernel.root_dir%/data/sqlite.db'
```

But when I execute the `composer update` command in my terminal, I have this error :

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_path". Did you
>   mean one of these: "database_user", "database_host", "database_port",
>   "database_name"?

and when I look at my parameters.yml I realize that my parameter "database_path" has been removed !!

Why `composer update` command do this ?

If I change my "database_path" to "database_name" for example, it works... I don't understand

**EDIT:** the solution was to add this parameter in `parameters.yml.dist`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 stop Composer installing parameters.yml.dist into parameters.yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451695/symfony2-stop-composer-installing-parameters-yml-dist-into-parameters-yml)