# change parameters.yml file in symfony 2 with heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I'm using Symfony 2.5 and I can not make changes to the parameters file because whenever I push any update it rebuilds the file.

I use the buildpack: https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php and my composer is this:

```js
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.9.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
           "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "heroku": {
        "newrelic": true,
        "document-root": "web",
        "index-document": "app.php",
        "compile": [
            "php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod"
        ],
        "php-config": [ 
            "date.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo",
            "display_errors=off",
            "short_open_tag=off"
        ]
    },
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    },
    "framework": "symfony2"
   }
   }
```

If anyone has any idea I would be very grateful

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19126638/1548376

Comment: Does not work, when giving a push to the heroku he makes application build again, even I have another problem, uploads of my web folder go into space, I lose everything when I push